# Adding a label to Theorems etc

Tags: marginpar

I would like to add some labels to Theorem (etc.) environments.  Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}[subsection]{Theorem}
\reversemarginpar

\begin{document}

Some text that goes before.

\begin{theorem}\marginpar{0x5af3}
Let $E$ be a Banach space.  If \ldots
\end{theorem}

Some text that comes after.

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the margin label appears higher up than the "Theorem" label.  I would like the text in the label to be at the same vertical level as the bold "Theorem" in the main text.

- I could fix this by putting the `\marginpar` into the text of the theorem, instead of straight after the `\begin{theorem}`.  But that's very messy.
- I had a look at the TeX source code for the `showkeys` package, and I see a lot of code which I don't understand, which deals with this issue (around boxes, and vertical lists etc.)  But I just don't understand this, nor how to re-create the effect.

I am looking for a LaTeX solution which is easy to understand.  Or, failing that, a "standard" solution, if this is possible?

Comment: try `\leavevmode\marginpar{0x5af3}` and next time please provide a full minimal example that others can copy and test as is instead of just a sniplet like this. A full minimal example makes it much faster to wokr on your problem.

Comment: @daleif  I added a fully working example.  Your simple fix does seem to work.  I had a read about `\leavevmode`.  Are there any side-effects I should be aware of?

Comment: Not 100% sure, there might be corner cases. I would of course not type `\leavevmode\marginpar{...}` every time, but rather place it in a macro, say `\markthm{...}`. What exactly is this marker anyway?

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I already planned to use macros.  The marker should be a "tag", in sense of https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tags  That is, a secondary "numbering system" so that if the Theorem is moved (so getting renumbered) the "tag" stays the same.